# Can't get AJAX POST working in Django

Tags: python, ajax, django, python-3.x

I can't do a POST ajax request in Django. If I do a GET request, it works fine. I think it may be a csrf token problem, but I can get it to work

My view:

```
@login_required
def add_share_points(request):
    user = request.user
    profile = request.user.profile

    if request.method == 'POST':
        value = 5.0

        # Premia o usuário ao compartilhar conteúdo
        VirtualCurrencyTransaction.objects.create(
            user=request.user,
            reason=2,
            description='Você completou seu perfil',
            value=value
        )

    return "ok"
```

My AJAX request:

```
$('.my-button').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var pointsCount = $(this).hasClass('homepage-facebook-share') ? 3 : 2;
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "/add_share_points",
        data: {
            points: pointsCount,
        }
    }).done(function() {
        alert('Posting completed.');
    }).fail(function(){
        alert('Error while posting.');
    });
});
```

In my script, I also have this setting:

```
function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/).test(method);
}

$.ajaxSetup({
    crossDomain: false,
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type)) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', CSRF_TOKEN);
        }
    }
});
```

What is wrong with my code? It gave my a 500 error code, but no further explanation in the logs.

Comment: Enable debug mode or configure logging and post the full stack trace.

Comment: You cannot return a string `"ok"` in your view function - that will fail with an error. You need to [return a `HttpResponse` object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/views/#writing-views).

Comment: @solarissmoke, I was just testing. The POST request doesnt even enter the method when I am debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will point out several things to correct, some are just ways to do it in a django manner and not problems.

**In your view**

```
 return HttpResponse(
            json.dumps({'result': 'ok',}),
            content_type="application/json"
        )
```

**In your ajax**

```
url: "/add_share_points",
```

should be:

```
url : {% url '<name in url.py>' %},
```

and you need to add (to the data object):

```
 csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
```

Inside the ajax request, insert this after data:

```
// handle a successful response
success : function(json) {
     if (json.result=== 'ok'){
         console.log('It works!');
     }else{
         console.log('Something wrong with response');
     }
// handle a non-successful response
error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
    console.log(err);
}
```

**In your script**

instead of `CSRF_TOKEN` use  `'{{ csrf_token }}'`

> Please use my suggestions and give me feedback and I will update the answer. The two with `csfrtoken` are probably the problems your having. If you put Django in Debug mode it will be easyer to find out.

**My Suggestion**

Create a [form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/) with what you need to post to gain some features in the validation process.

Comment: Thank you, I will try those. One thing: {{ csrf_token }} works in a .js file?

Comment: also, in the base.htm I have:
 <script>
        var CSRF_TOKEN = '{{ csrf_token }}';
 </script>

Comment: No it doesn't. Do `console.log` to understand if the value is correct in the .js file

Comment: Worked. I also needed to put a trailing slash in order do make the POST request

Comment: @TalesPádua I've just [answered a question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38849047/4470542) that may help you start on the right foot